# Read meta data form XML file into shared _Layout - ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am developing an application using ASP.NET Core razor pages. I have saved meta data in an XML file; the reason I save it in xml is that in CMS system I have given user the option to write and read to XML file so the user will be able to change meta data.

Now I want to read and show metadata `title` and `description` in shared `_layout.cshtml` so that same description appears on all pages. Since `_layout.cshtml` doesn't have an associated `.cs` file to write C# code in, I am not able to read the XML file.

I can read it in individual pages like the `index.cshtml.cs` i have shared by `XDocument` but not in shared `_layout.cshtml` for all pages.

**index.cshtml.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    /*
     * 
     * Reading Meta Title, Description, Keywords
     * 
     */
    var filepath = _env.ContentRootPath.ToString() + @"\meta-data.xml";

    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);

    // Run query
    IEnumerable<XElement> metaList = xmlDoc.Root.Elements("meta");

    var result = from a in metaList
                 select new
                        {
                             title = a.Element("title").Value.Trim(),
                             description = a.Element("description").Value.Trim(),
                             keywords = a.Element("keywords").Value.Trim()
                         };

    if (entity.DomainId == 1)   // jaeger
    {
         ViewData["xml_title"] = result.ElementAt(0).title;
         ViewData["xml_description"] = result.ElementAt(0).description;
         ViewData["xml_keywords"] = result.ElementAt(0).keywords;
     }
     else
     {
         ViewData["xml_title"] = result.ElementAt(1).title;
         ViewData["xml_description"] = result.ElementAt(1).description;
         ViewData["xml_keywords"] = result.ElementAt(1).keywords;
     }

     .....
}
```

**_layout.cshtml**

```
@using Jaeger.Services
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
@inject MenuMasterService menus
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    @*<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">*@
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - @ViewData["xml_title"]</title>
    <meta name="description" content="@ViewData["xml_description"] ">
    <meta name="keywords" content="@ViewData["xml_keywords"] ">
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your `entity`,for how to show metadata `title` and `description` in shared `_Layout.cshtml`,you could refer to the following code:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment _env;
@using System.Xml.Linq;

@{
    var filepath = _env.ContentRootPath.ToString() + @"\meta-data.xml";

    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);

    IEnumerable<XElement> metaList = xmlDoc.Root.Elements("meta");

    var result = from a in metaList
                 select new
                 {
                     title = a.Element("title").Value.Trim(),
                     description = a.Element("description").Value.Trim(),
                     keywords = a.Element("keywords").Value.Trim()
                 };

    ViewData["xml_title"] = result.ElementAt(0).title;
    ViewData["xml_description"] = result.ElementAt(0).description;
    ViewData["xml_keywords"] = result.ElementAt(0).keywords;     
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    @*<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">*@
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - @ViewData["xml_title"]</title>
    <meta name="description" content="@ViewData["xml_description"] ">
    <meta name="keywords" content="@ViewData["xml_keywords"] ">
.....
```

Comment: Not a very good idea, that code will be executed on every single page load. It would make much more sense to load the data once, or at least cache it, and inject that into the page

Comment: Thanks @Rena. I will try this.

Comment: And i agree with you also @Hanno. I will turn this into a service. will a transient service load once if i inject it?

Comment: Hi @AmirDora,if my answer worked for you,could you accept as answer?If not,please follow up to let me know.Refer to:[How to accept as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).